# Error JAVAC0000: error: package com.google.android.gms... does not exist

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

So I just got a new MAC, and I have so many errors when running my project. I haven't worked on the project for about a year now, and this happens:

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7YsR.png)

I have tried cleaning, rebuilding etc.. nothing seems to work. Tips?

I am using Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac Version 8.3.3 (build 8)

Comment: Hmm if you create and build a new solution, do you see the same issues

Comment: @Saamer - Tried to create a new solution now, with the default `Welcome to Xamarin.Forms` label, and it run successfully. No errors.

Comment: @Saamer Got all the errors gone now, but when the app starts, it is just a white screen.

Comment: Is it the same with other solutions?

Comment: @JessieZhang No, just this one.

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Comment: @JessieZhang - How can I share a basic demo? I only have the whole solution, witch is my hole app.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm facing a similar issue today. Did you resolve this @Camile